# jpql query: Having problems with case conditions when comparing nullable fields

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have the following basic class structure;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "payees")
public class Payee{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    private User user;
    ...
} 

@Entity
@Table(name = "bank_accounts")
@NamedQuery(name="[jpql-query-name]", query="[the-jpql-query]")
public class BankAccount{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Payee.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="payee_id")
    private Payee payee;
    ...
}
```

The use-case of the entities is such that `BankAccount` can belong to either a `User` or a `Payee` - but not both. Also, `Payee` always belongs to `User`.

See sample data below;

**(Users Table)**

```
ID          NAME
---------------------------------
1           Titilade Dangote 
2           Kenneth Effiong
3           Hassan Bonnyface
```

**(Payees Table)**

```
ID          NAME                    USER_ID
--------------------------------------------------
1           Ngozika Tijani          2
2           Tobiloba Da'Costa       3
3           Johnson Snowden         1
4           Farouk Nnamani          3
```

**(BankAccounts Table)**

```
ID      PAYEE_ID        USER_ID     OWNER_NAME
------------------------------------------------------
1       2               null        Tobiloba Da'Costa
2       null            3           Hassan Bonnyface
3       1               null        Ngozika Tijani
4       null            1           Titilade Dangote
5       4               null        Farouk Nnamani
```

Now the intention is to find Bank Account where `id=:bankAccountId` and return **`true`** if it is either owned by a User with `id=userId` or owned by a Payee that belongs to the User with `user.id=userId`. If otherwise, then return **`false`**.

So I write the following query to that effect

See `[the-jpql-query]` below;

```
SELECT (CASE 
            WHEN (b.user.id = :userId 
                    OR b.payee.user.id = :userId) 
            THEN (true) 
            ELSE (false) 
        END) 
FROM BankAccount b 
WHERE b.id = :bankAccountId
```

Following are samples of my expected results;

**`(bankAccountId = 2 and userId = 3)`**

```
ID      PAYEE_ID        USER_ID     OWNER_NAME          |   Result
------------------------------------------------------  |  --------
2       null            3           Hassan Bonnyface    |   (true)
```

**`(bankAccountId = 1 and userId = 3)`**

```
ID      PAYEE_ID        USER_ID     OWNER_NAME          |   Result
------------------------------------------------------  |  --------
1       2               null        Tobiloba Da'Costa   |   (true)
```

**`(bankAccountId = 4 and userId = 1)`**

```
ID      PAYEE_ID        USER_ID     OWNER_NAME          |   Result
------------------------------------------------------  |  --------
4       null            1           Titilade Dangote    |   (true)
```

**`(bankAccountId = 3 and userId = 2)`**

```
ID      PAYEE_ID        USER_ID     OWNER_NAME          |   Result
------------------------------------------------------  |  --------
3       1               null        Ngozika Tijani      |   (true)
```

However my query (`[the-jpql-query]`) keeps returning **`false`**. I suspect that it might be due to an inability to process the `b.payee.user.id=:userId` part of the query whenever payee is null

***To reiterate;***

> The intention is to find `BankAccount` where `id=:bankAccountId` and
>   return **`true`** if it is either owned by a `User` with `id=userId` or owned by
>   a Payee that belongs to the User with `user.id=userId`. If otherwise,
>   then return **`false`**

Please can someone point me in the right direction as to how to achieve this?

Comment: Side remark: Despite that your model is formally correct, it has performance implications: Resolving `b.user.id=:userId` as `b.user_id:=userId` and similar on payee will prevent unnecessary joins (you are checking the foreign key anyway, and in a normal model you have constraint checks to protect you from non-existing FK constraints). You will need to add an extra parameter in your models for this to reflect the key value as a non-object.

Comment: I actually already have a field called `owner_type` (whose value could only be either `PAYEE` or `USER`) in `BankAccount`... if that's not what you mean by saying "add an extra parameter in your models for this to reflect the key value as a non-object" then i'm not exactly sure how you mean.

Comment: I would add the column `user_id` from you `bankaccount` table to the bankaccount model so it can be queried direct without going to the user table first (hopefully more clear).

Comment: Oh yeah, now I get what you mean. Thanks. Problem now is that this is only part of a larger system where several other components I may not be aware of are making use `BankAccount`'s `user` field... Nonetheless, I'm still not clear how making the fields flat would help solve the problem in question... Could you please clarify in an Answer?

Comment: I do not have that answer either, sorry: Upvoted your question for more attention.

Answer (score 0):

the behavior of conditionals in jpql and sql with regard to null is highly questionable.  you should always try to use `is null`.

try something like:

```
WHEN (b.USER.id is null) THEN (b.PAYEE.USER.id = :user_id)
ELSE (b.USER.id = :user_id)
```

Comment: yes, you can check this out by testing `select 0 = 1 from dual` in oracle or just `select 0 = 1` in postgresql.